# How to break socket_accept() function in php?

Tags: php, sockets

I am doing a project related to php socket. My target is that I will show all client connected to server and show them in html file. However, if i put socket_accept() function in while loop, it won't break when no client connect and it will be there to wait a new client so html file will not be showed. Now, I want to while loop only accept all client in 10 second and then export result? I have tried with set_time_limit() but it's not ok. How to break socket_accept in php?

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
/* Allow the script to hang around waiting for connections. */
set_time_limit(10);

/* Turn on implicit output flushing so we see what we're getting
* as it comes in. */
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = "103.1.239.148";
$port = 10000;
// Maximum device
$maxdevice = 5;

// Create Socket
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($sock === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

if (!socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)) { 
    echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)); 
    exit; 
}

// Bind Socket to port
if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

// Start listening for connection
if (socket_listen($sock, $maxdevice) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

// Handling connection from client
$i=0; // Initial count variable 
while (true)
{
    $msgsock[++$i] = socket_accept($sock); // msgsock is a client connect to webserver
    if ($msgsock[$i] === false) {
        echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
        break;
    }
    $senddata="L";
    socket_write($msgsock[$i], $senddata, strlen($senddata)) or die("Couldn't write to client");
    $receive=socket_read($msgsock[$i],2048,PHP_BINARY_READ) or die ("Couldn't read from client");
    if ($receive !="")
    {
        include ("list.html");
    }
    if ($i==$maxdevice)
        break;
    socket_close($msgsock[$i]);  // Close connect of client
} 
socket_close($sock);  // Close socket of server
?>
```

Comment: The "right answer" here is to use `socket_set_nonblock()` on the socket before calling `socket_accept()`, and then use `socket_select()` to determine if there is something available on the socket.  In other words, you need to read up on "non-blocking sockets" -- there is no (good) way to break out of blocking calls on a blocking socket.

Comment: Thanks for your help